# LEFT JOIN (SELECT FROM WHERE >Values from another JOIN'ed table<)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I'm trying to do multiple left joins on a table in order to retrieve one row of information.

```
FROM THeaders th

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TItems) ti
                  ON th.rtid = ti.rtid

LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 MC, GH, GC, DI, DC FROM Prod **WHERE ti.MC = MC**) p
      ON ti.MC = p.MC AND (ti.AI IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Prod WHERE MC = ti.MC))
```

The idea is to get all the information from 'ti', and only one row from the 'p' table where the MC is equal to ti.MC. The 'p' table contains hundreds of rows with the same MC, but all the other fields can be assumed to have the same values (GH, GC, DI, DC)

The section marked with stars is the part I'm having issues with. I figure it's because, as the error "ti.MC could not be bound says", that the join to 'ti' hasn't yet been initialized, so can't be used within the select of another join.

Is there any way that I can get this to happen? My current workings are to see if I can use a nested join or possibly set a variable to use, but both are currently not proving fruitful.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Sql Server` it is done with `APPLY` operator. Something like this:

```
FROM THeaders th
LEFT JOIN TItems ti ON th.rtid = ti.rtid
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 MC, GH, GC, DI, DC FROM Prod WHERE ti.MC = MC) oa
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much, I'm still relatively new to SQL and hadn't seen the APPLY operator before. Time to read up on it. Thank you again! :)